# How to train a machine/deep learning model with data that has multiple input rows per day but only one row of label/ground-truth (output) data per day

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, dataset, lstm

I am doing a sleep data science experiment and I need a model that outputs multiple columns sleep quality measurement values (that are decimal numbers) for each input.

For training, I collected data using a smartphone (for input data) and a smartwatch (for label or output data). The smartphone collects MULTIPLE rows of sensor data such as accelerometer and gyroscope for ONE night. The smartwatch generates a SINGLE row of sleep quality indicator values (such as TWAK, NWAK, WASO, etc...) for ONE night. The structure of data looks as follows:

[image]

The above is a representation of my data. The left side is the phone feature data (with an undefined number of records per day based on how long the person was sleeping on that day) and the right side is the sleep quality measure data which is only one value per day. I need to train a model with this data and online sources seem to suggest LSTM is the way to go. Can you please give me a suggestion or point me to a resource that would help me do a prediction on this type of dataset structure using python? Tensorflow would be prefered.

Thank you in advance! I can explain it however many times you need so feel free to ask me any question.

Answer (score 2):

As my understanding, you have sensors (X), each sample has K dimensions, and each day contains L rows of samples. The number L can be varied day by day, which depends on how long a person slept per day.

I think you can train a [sequence-to-sequence (seq2seq) with LSTM-based](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) model (with input X) to encode and decode itself. So this seq2seq model can get diverse sequence length but generates the same encoded feature's dimension. The loss function of this step could be L2 or mean-absolute value between the reconstructed output and input.

Then the encoded feature can be used to make a prediction for the single output (i.e., sleep quality) by another simple LSTM model or fully connected layer. The loss function of this regression task could be L2 or mean-absolute value as well.

In general, you can learn a representation of the sensor data (with varied sequence length) by using seq2seq (i.e., a form of autoencoder), then use the compressed representation (from the encoder) to predict the single output (i.e., sleep quality).

However, this approach could be lossy due to the compressed representation cannot capture a fully sequential relationship as the original data, and it will be used as an input for the regression task.

An improved approach could be that instead of selecting only the last hidden states of the encoder as the representation, you can select a certain number of last hidden states (e.g., a minimum number of L over days) as the encoded representation. But I have not seen any paper that did this idea.